# Multiple regression with sparse X

Tags: multiple-regression, sparse

I would like to run the multiple regression:
$$y = X \beta + \epsilon \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
with:

- $n \sim 2 \times 10^6$
- $p \sim 10^4$
- $X$ sparse

  - 70% of rows have 1 non-zero value
  - 15% of rows have 2 non-zero values
  - 5% of rows have 3 non-zero values
  - ...
- $y$ follows a bell-shaped distribution
- $\{X_j\}$ are expected to be mildely positively correlated

The problem is the inversion of the $(p \times p)$ matrix.

Hence, as a shortcut I ran the $p$ regressions (indexed by $j$):
$$y^{(j)} = \beta_{j} x^{(j)} + \gamma_{j} z^{(j)} + \epsilon^{(j)} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$
where:

- $x^{(j)}$ are the stacked non-zero values of $X_j$
- $y^{(j)}$ are the corresponding values of $y$
- $z^{(j)}$ are the sums of the other (non-zero) components from the corresponding row where each of the $x^{(j)}$s is drawn from

this leads to:

- $\sum n_j \sim 6 \times 10^6$.
- $p_j = 2$

and I then interpret $\{\beta_{j}\}$ as some proxy for $\beta$.

**Questions:**

1. Is (2) a sensible way of simplifying the problem? What am I leaving aside?
2. Does (1) belong to a known set of linear models and are there well identified methods to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: E-notation would conventionally require mantissas in $\left[1,10\right)$ (ignoring signs), so the "$10\text{e}3$ should presumably be $1.\text{e}4$ -- but in any case the more conventional $1.\times 10^4$ would be easier to read. I suggest you use that instead (and similarly for each other use of E-notation).

Comment: Additionally, when you say "[multivariate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_regression)", that traditionally refers to the dimension of $y$ (that is, where each observation, $y_i$ is vector-valued). If $y_i$ is univariate, the regression with multiple predictors would usually be called *[multiple regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_linear_regression)*. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multivariate-regression/info to see that the tag you have used is defined to be consistent with this convention.

Comment: now fixed, thanks

Comment: See [this stored google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=effective+numerical+methods+for+least+square++regression+with+sparse+predictors&client=ubuntu&hs=G3Z&channel=fs&sxsrf=AOaemvJQ0qZjZ7_S1HNv5NGXZEh5vTXKWA%3A1630684954531&ei=GkcyYdTEH9TV1sQPxtyd2As&oq=effective+numerical+methods+for+least+square++regression+with+sparse+predictors&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAgjECc6BAghEApKBAhBGABQu0pYz2Rg029oAXACeACAAWGIAc0JkgECMTSYAQCgAQHIAQnAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjUudHrluPyAhXUqpUCHUZuB7sQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)